# Can't instantiate DLL created with Visual FoxPro

Tags: soap, dll, wsdl, visual-foxpro

Currently I have to create web service for existing application created with Visual FoxPro. I can compile DLL from class library, generate WSDL from DLL, but calling this DLL using wsdl from SoapUi gives me the following error:

> Instantiating the dispatch object for method *companyadd* failed

Also, I can't open this DLL in OLE/COM Viewer. It gives the following error: [IClassFactory::CreateInstance failed Unspecified error E_FAIL($800004005)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PraxL.png)

Can somebody give me some idea how i can elucidate what the reason of the problem?

For some DLL's created from this app I don't have such errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back when I had to build OLE/COM servers in VFP, most of the time it ended up being permissions.  Even for building, you would have to start VFP "Run as Administrator" so it could write the entries into the Windows registry.

Then comes the error 800004005. that too has been based on permissions (in my experience).  For that, I had to always go into the COM Server configuration from Windows.

From remembering 32/64 bit, you need to explicitly run the DCOM configuration in 32-bit mode.  to do so, from a DOS Command window, do

```
MMC comexp.msc /32
```

This tells the DCOM Configuration to show the 32-bit based COM servers (VFP only runs under 32-bit mode)

Then, expand the treeview controller for Console Root -> Component Services -> Computers -> My Computer -> DCOM Config.  Then scroll down to your application.  You may need to use the GUID if the class name is not referenced / shown in the list.  Right-click on it and select properties.  On the "Identity" tab you can identify which account to use for access to the COM object.  Just for TESTING AND CONFIRMATION, set the user account to and administrator level account and try.  Once that is confirmed, you know it is permission access or not.  Then remove admin and put another lower-level user account.  When it fails, you would then need to make sure that the "user" has adequate permissions to any paths that might be in play for your process.

Hopefully this helps, but again, most of this was from years ago doing COM servers with VFP.